# How to click images in open cv python after a certain interval of time and simaltaneously save a fixed number of those captured images?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

Since I am very much new to this language, with whatever little knowledge I have, I have written code.

The code is getting executed thrice, but the three images are being overwritten and at the end there is just one image that is available instead of 3 different images (which is my goal).

```
import cv2
#helps in turning on the camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#camera clicks the images for 3 times
a = 0
while (a < 3):
    a = a+1

#creating a frame
    check, frame = cap.read()
    print(check)
    print(frame)

#conversion of image to grayscale
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#shows the frame
    cv2.imshow("capturing",image)

#Saving Of image
    status = cv2.imwrite('path of where the image is to be saved.jpg',image) 
    print("Image written to file-system : ",status)

#turns off the camera
cap.release


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can use string formatting to insert a number or something else at the end of the file name so that they are not saving over the same path. Try something like `filename = 'image_{:02d}.jpg'.format(a)`. The `02d` part means "write this as a two-digit number, leading with a zero" so that'll save each image as `image_01.jpg`, `image_02.jpg`, `image_03.jpg`. Docs for format: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format

Comment: Also `release` is a method, not an attribute --- you need to call it like a function with `cap.release()` at the end of your program. Also, you need to call `waitKey()` directly after `imshow()` if you want to preview all three frames (`waitKey()` is what actually displays the image).

Comment: This really helped ! thanks a lot. I was able to save three different images.

Comment: what if i want a delay of 20 seconds between the images that are being captured ?

Comment: Is this from a webcam or from a video? You can seek to 20s into a video with `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 20000)` (sets the millisecond position of the video to 20000 ms, i.e. 20 seconds). If it's a webcam then you can just sleep for 20 seconds with `time.sleep(20)` from the `time` module in the standard library.

Comment: The images were captured from a webcam. Time.sleep() worked. thanks a ton !